# How can I apply CSS to dropdownlists?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I want to make sure that all of my form fields uses the same font.  I have:

```
 input
 {
   font-size:1em;
   font-family:Verdana;
 }
```

But this doesn't get applied to drop down lists, nor to multi-line text boxes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add select (for dropdowns) and textarea (for multiline text boxes):

```
input, select, textarea {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: Verdana;
}
```